# out file is not according to the code in python

Tags: python

I have written this code to print a chessboard.
According to this code when x<256 and y<256 (1st box) then the **Last *ELSE* Portion** of the code will be executed which sets rgb=(255,255,255) which is the rgb of white color, but the output image shows first box as black please help.

The Code is:

```
import struct

image_width = 512
image_height = 512
box_width = 256
box_height = 256
bits_per_pixel = 24

# bitmap file header
data = 'BM' # Windows 3.1x, 95, NT, ... etc.
data += struct.pack('i', bits_per_pixel / 8 * image_width * image_height) # The size of the BMP file in bytes = header + (color bytes * w * h)
data += struct.pack('h', 0) # Reserved
data += struct.pack('h', 0) # Reserved
data += struct.pack('i', 0) # The offset, i.e. starting address, of the byte where the bitmap image data (pixel array) can be found.

# bitmap header (BITMAPCOREHEADER)
data += struct.pack('i', 12) # The size of this header (12 bytes)
data += struct.pack('h', image_width) # width
data += struct.pack('h', image_height) # height
data += struct.pack('h', 1) # The number of color planes, must be 1
data += struct.pack('h', bits_per_pixel) # The number of bits per pixel, which is the color depth of the image. Typical values are 1, 4, 8, 16, 24 and 32.

def rgb_to_str(r, g, b):
    return chr(r) + chr(g) + chr(b)

for y in xrange(image_height):
    for x in xrange(image_width):
        if (y / box_height) % 2:
            if (x / box_width) % 2:
                data += rgb_to_str(255, 255, 255)
            else:
                data += rgb_to_str(0, 0, 0)
        else:
            if (x / box_width) % 2:                
                data += rgb_to_str(0, 0, 0)
            else:
                data += rgb_to_str(255, 255, 255)

with open('out.bmp', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does only only one Box look wrong? Could you show us what the output looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Actually looks like you copied my code from the answer to question [python code without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493095/python-code-without-libraries/30493575#30493575).
But you forgot to set the offset, it must be `26`, but in your version it is `0`.

Correct bitmap file header must be:

```
# bitmap file header
data = 'BM' # Windows 3.1x, 95, NT, ... etc.
data += struct.pack('i', 26 + bits_per_pixel / 8 * image_width * image_height) # The size of the BMP file in bytes = header + (color bytes * w * h)
data += struct.pack('h', 0) # Reserved
data += struct.pack('h', 0) # Reserved
data += struct.pack('i', 26) # The offset, i.e. starting address, of the byte where the bitmap image data (pixel array) can be found.
```

By the way, I've found a mistake. BMP's colormap is BGR (not RGB), so to write color pixels use function:

```
def rgb_to_bmp_data(r, g, b):
    return chr(b) + chr(g) + chr(r)
```

And to fix color boxes try to use:

```
import math
row_bytes = width * (bits_per_pixel / 8)
row_padding = int(math.ceil(row_bytes / 4.0)) * 4 - row_bytes

for y in xrange(image_height - 1, -1, -1):
    for x in xrange(image_width):
        if (y / box_height) % 2:
            if (x / box_width) % 2:
                data += rgb_to_bmp_data(255, 255, 255)  # x=1, y=1
            else:
                data += rgb_to_bmp_data(0, 0, 0)  # x=0, y=1
        else:
            if (x / box_width) % 2:
                data += rgb_to_bmp_data(0, 0, 0)  # x=1, y=0
            else:
                data += rgb_to_bmp_data(255, 255, 255)  # x=0, y=0
    data += '\x00' * row_padding
```

The out is now according to the code:

[image]

I've added x and y values.

Comment: Yep, I was just about to post that there is an issue with the header. I had it print 1 and 0 to terminal when making colors and it looked exactly as intended.

Comment: I've found the problem, check answer

Comment: please tell why you have used xrange(image_height - 1, -1, -1) and not xrange(image_height)?

Comment: I've used it because of BITMAPCOREHEADER header. For this header type pixels array stored from the top to bottom.

Comment: Also I've added padding. If output BMP image's bytes in a row is not a multiple of 4 (it depends on the width), then without padding the result will be incorrect.